# Weird results using PHP-Imagick getImageSignature method

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I´m trying to use PHP Imagick´s getImageSignature method to compare different images and see if they are equal, but I´m getting different signature even with same image file when the method is called from different computers with different versions of ImageMagick and OS.

Should I always get the same signature in these conditions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I always get the same signature in these conditions?

Short answer is no.

The [Imagick::getImageSignature](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick_class.c#L6774) wraps [MagickGetImageSignature](http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/api/MagickWand/magick-image_8c.html#a9a30c84da6d65c201a86e4afa34184d1) which generates a signature at run-time based virtual pixels in memory & Quantum colorspace. The latter being influenced by the configuration options at compile time, or environment parameters. Differences in versions, and host architecture will contribute to the variations of the image signature.

As the signature is just a SHA-256 digest, it would be simpler to generate one yourself.

```php
$signature = sha1($image->getImageBlob());
// or subclass the method
class MyImagick extends Imagick {
 public function getMyImageSignature() {
   return sha1($this->getImageBlob());
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but your soultion it´s not working neither. It´s producing two different hashs from the same file.

Comment: Fair enough. Sounds like the problem exists in your application, and not with imagemagick. Please post your code, and the test case that's failing.

Comment: The code I used is as simple as the example you presented:

    $imagick = new Imagick( 'demo.jpg' );

    echo sha1( $imagick->getImageBlob() );


and with that piece of code I get 2 different strings using the same file but 2 different OS.

**System A: **
Windows 2003 (32bits)
PHP 5.4.11
ImageMagick 6.8.3-0 2013-02-13 Q8


**System B:**
Debian 7.0
PHP 5.4.4
ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-11-06 Q16



You can check the demo file at http://salom.me/demo.jpg 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the demo image. When the JPEG uncompresses into the virtual memory, the differences between **Q8** & **Q16** would mean that the 32-bit Windows 2003 will be losing precision. Even with the demo image only having a depth 8-bit. Deferent signatures are correct behavior, as the same file on disk does not guarantee the same file in memory.

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty fair but I have also tested the file with 2 different computers running both Debian and Image Magick Q16. Again the same result: 2 different signatures and 2 different results on sha1(getImageBlob()). I think I´m defeated and I have to use the same machine to generate every single signature on this project. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and your help.